# How to prove $\frac{6n}{n-6}$ can not be integer when $n >42$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This was a junior math contest question. However, it's not obvious for me.
Could anyone offer a clue?

Comment: Asking others to complete contest questions for you is not an effective way to learn how to complete them yourself.  All aquestions, contest, homework, or otherwise, must include far more context that merely a problem statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Specifically, for elegance and simplicity of lhf's solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{6n}{n-6} = 6 + \frac{36}{n-6}
$$
This is an integer iff the last term is an integer iff $n-6$ divides $36$. In particular, $n-6 \le 36$, which gives $n \le 42$.

We can continue and conclude that the fraction is an integer iff $$n \in \{-30,-12,-6,-3,0,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,12,15,18,24,42\}$$

Answer (score 3):

By the Euclidean algorithm,
$$\gcd(6n,n-6)=\gcd(n-6,6n-6(n-6))=\gcd(n-6,36).$$
For $n>42$, this is strictly less than $n-6$. So $n-6$ doesn't divide $6n$.